# Dynamic creation of object instances

Tags: c#, dynamic

We have a system that creates dynamically defined objects as a core aspect of the processing. I would like to be able to create an class object and make these objects instances of this class, implementing all of the functionality that this particular object has.

The problem is, these objects really need to dynamically inherit from a base class, and override null methods etc. In essence, I need something of a dynamic class structure (and I have proposed compiling the definitions into a proper class model, but that is some distance away). The best approach i can come up with is to create a class instance with a set of blank properties, and dyamically replace these properties with methods if these features are implemented.

I have also looked at Castles DynamicProxy approach, which might be a useful route (intercepting the calls and actioning them if appropriate), but this seems more complex than it should be.

So any suggestions? What would the best, most .Net-like approach to this be? As I look at the problem, it seems like there should be a really good and easy solution.

---

Just to help, a simple example (semi-pseudocode - I know it is not fully working):

```
class thing
{
    public void Process()
    {
        foo();
        bar();
    }
    private foo(){}
    private bar(){}
}

a=new thing() {foo=DoFoo}
b=new thing() {bar=DoBar}
```

I want to be able to call a.Process and b.Process, and have them both run. Bear in mind that these objects have some 20-30 properties/methods that might need setting (setting them is easy, but some of them might be substantial methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> create a class instance with a set of blank properties, and dyamically replace these properties with methods if these features are implemented

This sounds a lot like the "decorator" design pattern might be a good choice for you here. You basically implement a set of functionalities and then build your objects by subsequently assigning several "decorations" (functionalities) to a baseobject.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/479635/UnderstandingplusandplusImplementingplusDecoratorp seems to be a very good summary with clear examples on how and when to use decorator patterns

However if your properties heavily interact with each other, or need a significant different implementation depending on other "decorations" i would not suggest using a decorator. In that case you might need to get a bit more specific on your requirements.

Comment: I did look at decorators. My concern was whether adding 20 decorators to an object would be appropriate and efficient. I think most of the interactions could be managed by this process, adding sets of functions.

Comment: Since decorating the objects is usually done by the applikation at run-time this should not be a problem. The decorator pattern is almost as efficient as just subclassing your baseclass. However if you need to manually create decorated objects by calling 20+ decorators in your code, i would share your concern about the appropriate approach.

Comment: It is the scale of the creation dynamicism that worries me. For just one or two, decorators are clear. For small objects with dynamic functionality, the DynamicObject is appropriate. But these will be large, highly dynamic objects (with large, highly dynamic child objects!), so it seemed worth while asking for insight.

Comment: This sounds to me like the functionalities of your objects change quite drastically depending on your decorations? From your initial post and the example you provided, I would still stick with my suggestion to implement this as a decorator pattern. However if you are worried about the complexity, it might be worth a shot to think about if it is actually necessary to make the object fully dynamic on this level, or if you can break the functionalities down a bit to make things more static. It is quite hard to judge your situation without knowing the exact context though.

Comment: Just to clarify: If you are "only" switching functionalities on and off with your decorations (or doing something of similar complexity) the count of 20-30 decorators would not worry me. Making these objects highly dynamic is what you want after all. However the decorator pattern will be really hard to create if your decorations interfere with each other! If you manage to set it up, it will still be a good foundation, but then the problem is more about managing and keeping track of your dynamic functionalities and their interactions than about the design choice.

Comment: I don't see why DynamicObject would not be suited for large objects. I use it as an entity wrapper (to make them observable) and works like a charm, even for large entities. You can separate the functionality as you wish and don't really need to put it all in a large class (you can subclass it as much as you'd want). I'm not sure what the *real* problem is (other than what you stated), but from your comments and the question, I think you are overthinking it and making an overly complex solution, As I said, without the real problem in hand, it's hard to say this is justified or not

Comment: I am not ruling DynamicObject out. The aim is to provide a more maintainable system for developers, and an efficient system in the field. I suppose my concern is that the Try aspects of the dynamic object might prove expensive in terms of run-time performance.

Comment: In general, all kinds of runtime dynamicness bring performance issues. Have you considered having a helper object that stacks processing actions (kind of like an event, where the users would be subscribing delegates to it) instead of constructing dynamic objects? As I said, without knowing the actual problem is hard to give good solutions, but without more details the event/action queue would solve the problem *stated in the question* and would be easy and performant

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I really understand your requirements, but have you looked at the `DynamicObject` class?

The idea behind it is that you derive from it, and every time a member is accessed, it gets a call to `TryGetMember`, `TrySetMember`, or `TryInvokeMember` for methods, where you can do your custom logic.

You can make a base class inheriting from `DynamicObject` then make the set of classes you want by deriving from that base class, implementing the logic on each one of them, this way you can have both defined members, and other non-defined ones which you can use using a `dynamic` type.

Check the [documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject(v=vs.110).aspx) for `DynamicObject`

#### Alternative

Otherwise, as a very simple solution and based on the pseudo-code you provided only (which admittedly might be a little simple for the requirements stated in the question), you could just make a `Thing` class which has `Action` properties:

```
class Thing
{
    public void Process()
    {
       if(Foo!=null) Foo();
       if(Bar!=null) Bar();
    }
    public Action Foo {get;set;}
    public Action Bar {get;set;}
}

var a=new Thing() {Foo=DoFoo};
var b=new Thing() {Bar=DoBar};
a.Process();
b.Process();
```